# Pending intent get service

Tags: android, android-intent, service, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am having a problem getting my `pendingIntent` to fire. I have done some troubleshooting using the logcat etc. and in the end I am almost positive that my problem is actually in my `pendingIntent` method. The times I have set are correct, and the method is getting called, but nothing happens at the scheduled times. 
Here is the method that I use to create the `pendingIntent`

```
public void scheduleAlarm(){
    Log.d("Alarm scheduler","Alarm is being scheduled");
    Intent changeVol = new Intent();
    changeVol.setClass(this, VolumeService.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, changeVol, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, sender);
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Volume Adjusted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Here is the service class:

```
public class VolumeService extends Service{

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d("Service", "Service has been called.");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Called!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

The log in the `scheduleAlarm()` class is working as I planned but then nothing happens, so I assume it is my `pendingIntent`.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please provide how you get time value? Do you use System. currentTimeMillis() + some time to delay? Did you define service in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @VladimirLichonos The time is provided from the user using a `timePicker dialog` and I have triple checked using the logCat to be sure that the time is being chosen correctly; and it is. For example, I checked it earlier today and I inputted 3:45 pm, (MST) and when I checked the `long` value saved it correctly came out to be 3:45 pm (MST) on July 30 2013. As to the second part of your question, I added to the manifest using the following snippet `<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".services.VolumeService" />`.

Comment: Well, it seems fine to me, but I'd try to test more with canceling the alarm and cancel and  create again pending intent. Also trying to use just System.currentTimeMillis() for test purpose. It should work and may show you where the problem was.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured it out! The problem was in the Service class, I changed a few other things around too.
However, I believe the main problem was that in my service class in the `onCreate` method I was trying to run my code. But this needed to be done in the `onStartCommand` method

```
public class VolumeService extends Service{

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
 }


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

and a few changes were made in the class starting the service as seen here:

```
    public void scheduleAlarm(){
    Log.d("Alarm scheduler","Alarm is being scheduled");
    Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmSettings.this, VolumeService.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(AlarmSettings.this, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pintent);
}
```

Comment: does this work for you even when the app is killed? I tried similar code but it seems to run only if the app is still alive (which misses the point...). The AlarmManager does not even fire the alarm according to logcat, not to mention invoking the intent..

Comment: @SagiMann-TROPHiT yes for me it runs fine even if it is killed, as you said, that is kind of the point. Sorry I can't help more.